# Como deixar os endpoints de uma API, feita com Spring Boot, visíveis apenas para as paginas da aplicação?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, angular-routes

Tenho uma aplicação onde o back-end foi feito em Java com Spring Boot, e o front foi feito em Angular. Faço o deploy do projeto Angular buildado na pasta **src/main/resources/static**.

Na situação atual os endpoints da api, consumidos pelo front, também podem ser acessados ao digitar o caminho dos mesmos no navegador.

**Ex.:** A página [localhost:8080/Index.html](http://localhost:8080/Index.html) consome o endpoint [localhost:8080/api/exemplo](http://localhost:8080/api/exemplo) para mostrar seu conteúdo.

O que devo fazer para que a rota [localhost:8080/api/exemplo](http://localhost:8080/api/exemplo) seja acessível **somente** pelo [localhost:8080/Index.html](http://localhost:8080/Index.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione a dependência do módulo spring security e implemente a classe abstrata WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, você poderá no método definir as restrições de acesso a cada path da sua aplicação, você poderá adicionar eventualmente um filtro JWT e então para acessar os recursos será necessário que sua aplicação front passe um token a cada requisição para ter acesso a resposta
Pesquise artigos sobre o módulo que mencionei e sobre integração do mesmo com o conceito de JWT, provavelmente se encaixa no seu cenário

Comment: Valeu man, consegui, obrigado pelo Norte